# Doing group by on one hot encoded columns PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following dataframe called `df`. I want for each sector column (`sector_`) to basically do a group by and get the unique ids for each sector. The sector is denoted as 1 for each row if the id is apart of that sector. How can i do this group by if the columns are one hot encoded?

```
id winner sector_food sector_learning sector_parenting sector_consumer
1  1      1           0               0                0
1  0      1           0               0                0
2  1      0           0               0                0 
2  0      1           0               0                0
3  1      0           0               0                1
```

expected output

```
sector             unique_id
sector_food        2
sector_learning    0
sector_parenting   0
sector_consumer    1
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by unique ID?

Comment: For each sector i want to get a count of the unique ids (id column). so for the `sector_food` column there are two unique ids : 1 and 3

Comment: sorry i meant 1 and 2*

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
out = df.drop(["id", "winner"], 1).multiply(df.id, 0).nunique().subtract(1)

#sector_food         2
#sector_learning     0
#sector_parenting    0
#sector_consumer     1
#dtype: int64
```

---

To get your exact expected output you can add:

```
out = out.rename_axis("sector").to_frame("unique_id")

#                  unique_id
#sector                     
#sector_food               2
#sector_learning           0
#sector_parenting          0
#sector_consumer           1
```

Comment: Clever. Also just personal preference, but `df.filter(like='sector_')` feels cleaner than the `drop()`.

Comment: @tdy thank you! Using `filter` may be a more general case depending on the situation. Feel free to edit it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.drop('winner',axis=1).groupby(level=0).sum().gt(0).sum().to_frame('unique_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
winner = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
sector_food = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
sector_learning = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sector_parenting = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sector_consumer = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ids,
    'winner': winner,
    'sector_food': sector_food,
    'sector_learning': sector_learning,
    'sector_parenting': sector_parenting,
    'sector_consumer': sector_consumer
})

print(df)
```

output

```
   id  winner  sector_food  sector_learning  sector_parenting  sector_consumer
0   1       1            1                0                 0                0
1   1       0            1                0                 0                0
2   2       1            0                0                 0                0
3   2       0            1                0                 0                0
4   3       1            0                0                 0                1
```

You can do

```
_df = (df
       # drop unused cols
       .drop('winner', axis=1)
       # melt with 'id' as index
       .melt(id_vars='id')     
       # drop all duplicates
       .drop_duplicates(['id', 'variable', 'value'])
       # sum unique values
       .groupby('variable').value.sum()
      )
print(_df)
```

output

```
variable
sector_consumer     1
sector_food         2
sector_learning     0
sector_parenting    0
Name: value, dtype: int64
```